# Conflicts in remove() function in firebase Realtime database

Tags: vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, nuxt.js

I'm using firebase realtime database in my nuxt js(**Nuxt 3.0.0-rc.12**) application.

I can able to remove the data at all the locations except at one position named ***User permission***.

Here is my code..

Note: I pushed the data using firebase push() method and get the key and stored it in variable named **key**
Code mentioned below works well.

```
const fromDatabase = child(ref(db, 'test'),key) //ref() returns firebase reference 
remove(fromDatabase) //removes data at specified location
```

Here's my next code..

```
const fromDatabase = child(ref(db, 'User permission'),key) //ref() returns firebase reference 
remove(fromDatabase) //removes data at specified location
```

Above code gives error `Uncaught TypeError: indexedChildren.remove is not a function`. I searched internet and got no solution. Then I changed the name ***User permission*** to ***User permissions***. It works well. After few days, the problem is again happening. Just as I above said, Now I can able to remove data at all other locations except at 'User permissions'. How to solve this issue?

Comment: It is unlikely that somebody can help based on the little information you shared so far. I recommend reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Following the guidance in those increases the chances that someone can help.

Comment: I think, now my question is in understandable way.